# AWS Auto Scaling DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was thinking exactly how Amazon AWS handles the data replication on the fly when a new DB instance is launched when auto scaling is turned on?

I'm more interested about Cassandra, MySql, Redis, Riak, but of course would love to know about others too but after I get clarity about the ones mentioned.

It is confusing me a lot.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should clarify about what DB you're talking. AWS offers quite a few.

Comment: Updated the right technologies

Answer (score 0):

Core architecture comes from MySQL replication.. where every transaction is also saved as part of bin log. Also, AWS keeps taking snapshot frequently..Now, suppose you start data replication .. It will first take the latest snapshot --> recover it --> (that snapshot also has information that this snapshot has information till what pointer in bin log) --> now, it starts playing bin log on top of new db ( generated from snapshot ) till catch-up is done.

After catch up is done --> then this bin log keeps getting played in real time on replica server.

Note that MySQL gives many options of creating bin log; for example statement based (actual sql statement is logged), row based(all the rows are logged ) or mixed.

Comment: This may be valid for RDS MySQL. Not for anything driven by Aurora or for DynamoDB.

Comment: DynamoDB I do not know.. Aurora is based on top of MySql or Postgres and both of these are based on bin log concept.

Comment: Nope. Aurora doesn't use the mysql or postgres replication method. It uses it's own storage subsystem replication and has adapted the mysql or postgres (and mongodb recently) to run on top of it. Read this: https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/p1041-verbitski.pdf

Comment: @rdas Can you please answer: What in case of Cassandra, Riak, Redis, PostgreSql ?

Comment: This is a very broad question not suited for SO. Suggest you do some reading. Start here maybe: https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Data-Intensive-Applications-Reliable-Maintainable/dp/1449373321

Comment: @rdas You mean there will be problem in case of DynamoDB and Postgres?

Comment: @rdas Can you please just tell me whether auto scaling will work with cassandra, redis without any problem or not?

Comment: @Deepak Can you please just tell me whether auto scaling will work with cassandra, redis without any problem or not?

Comment: Yes cassandra for sure works fine for auto-scaling.. Even redis should be just fine..